# Expo Build in XCODE gives error: CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler

Tags: xcode, react-native, macos, compiler-errors, apple-m1

I am trying to run an expo build so that I can use it in the XCode simulator.

I am running on a Macbook M1 chip.

I have simply opened the Expo folder from xCode, then try to click on the run button and I get the following error:

```
Build fails with the below errors
The following build commands failed:
        CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler (in target 'lottie-react-native' from project 'Pods')
        CompileSwiftSources normal x86_64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler (in target 'ExpoModulesCore' from project 'Pods')
        CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler (in target 'ExpoModulesCore' from project 'Pods')
        CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler (in target 'expo-dev-menu' from project 'Pods')
        CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler (in target 'expo-dev-launcher' from project 'Pods')
        PhaseScriptExecution [CP-User]\ Generate\ Specs /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBReactNativeSpec.build/Script-84523FB004E42E06A56C6DE861F4376B.sh (in target 'FBReactNativeSpec' from project 'Pods')
```

Tried below resolution options but doesn't seem to work

1. Re-installation of pod file and its packages,
2. Excluding the arm64 arch from project in xcode
3. Changing the arch to Standard architectures (including 64-bit) (armv7, armv7s, arm64)
4. pod update, pod disintegrate, pod install
5. open Xcode via rosetta, change the arch in pod file in code to arm64

Versions:
npm version - 6.14.17
node version - v14.19.2
expo version -5.4.3
react-native version- 7.0.3

Comment: What xcode version are you running?

Comment: The latest version - 13.3.1

Comment: Downgrade to xcode 12, that should solve your problems. Follow this guide to downgrade: https://www.wootechy.com/iphone-issue/downgrade-xcode/

Comment: Did downgrading to xcode 12 fix this issue? started having this problem after following the bare react native installation: https://docs.expo.dev/development/installation/#1-installation. it worked fine with expo run:ios but we needed it to run on Expo Go too

Comment: Did you solve the issue?